# php yii framework issue with objects (2)

Tags: php, mysql, yii

This is somewhat the continuation to the question I already posted "[php yii framework issue with objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35070908/php-yii-framework-issue-with-objects/35072060#35072060)", but a new problem arised so I am posting a new question for the sake of better code display and explanation of what's wrong. This is the problematic part of the code:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'predmet-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    //array(
    //  'name'=>'naziv',
    //  'value'=>$model->studijskiProgram->naziv,
    //),
    'sp_id',
    'naziv',
    'semestar',
    'predavanja',
    'vjezbe',
    //array(
    //  'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    //),
),
)); ?>
```

And this is the code of the model class where relations are located:

```
<?php

/**
* This is the model class for table "predmet".
*
* The followings are the available columns in table 'predmet':
* @property integer $id
* @property integer $sp_id
* @property string $naziv
* @property integer $semestar
* @property integer $predavanja
* @property integer $vjezbe
*/
   class Predmet extends CActiveRecord
   {
     /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Predmet the static model class
     */

const STATUS_O = "O";
const STATUS_I = "I";
const STATUS_VP = "VP";

public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

/**
 * @return string the associated database table name
 */
public function tableName()
{
    return 'predmet';
}

/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('sp_id, naziv, semestar, predavanja, vjezbe, status', 'required'),
        array('sp_id, semestar, predavanja, vjezbe', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('naziv', 'length', 'max'=>100),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, sp_id, naziv, semestar, predavanja, vjezbe, status', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.

    //POVEZUJEMO PREDMET I STUDIJSKI PROGRAM
    //BELONGS_TO ide za vezu jedan u vise(kad na stranu 1 pisemo kome pripada)
    //HASMANY ili HAS_MANY (?) JE ZA VISE U JEDAN

    /*ovo prvo 'studijskiProgram' je kao pokazivac na studijski program s kojim je povezan
    Neka imamo $predmet. da bi pristupili nazivu studijskog programa kome pripada, koristicemo:
    $predmet->studijskiProgram->naziv
    */
    return array(
        'studijskiProgram' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'StudijskiProgram', 'sp_id')
    );
}

/**
 * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'sp_id' => 'Studijski program',
        'naziv' => 'Naziv',
        'semestar' => 'Semestar',
        'predavanja' => 'Predavanja',
        'vjezbe' => 'Vjezbe',
        'status' => 'Status'
    );
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
 * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
 */
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('sp_id',$this->sp_id);
    $criteria->compare('naziv',$this->naziv,true);
    $criteria->compare('semestar',$this->semestar);
    $criteria->compare('predavanja',$this->predavanja);
    $criteria->compare('vjezbe',$this->vjezbe);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}


//Funkcija za punjenje Combo box-a (Wombo)
public function uzmiStatusPredmeta()
{
    return array(
            self::STATUS_O => 'Obavezni',
            self::STATUS_I => 'Izborni',
            self::STATUS_VP => 'VP'
    );
}

public function uzmiSpisakStudijskihPrograma()
{
    $query = 'select id, naziv from studijski_program';
    $rezultat = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
    $spisak = CHtml::listData($rezultat,'id','naziv');  //prikazuje naziv, krije ID(valjda radi combo boxa-wombo ?)

    return $spisak;
}
public function vratiProgram()
{
    $query = 'select s.naziv 
    from studijski_program s,predmet p
    where p.sp_id = s.id';
    $rezultat = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryScalar();
    //$rezultat1 = implode($rezultat);
    //$rezultat2 = implode($rezultat1);
    return $rezultat;
}
public function vratiProgramId()
{
    $query = 'select s.id 
    from studijski_program s,predmet p
    where p.sp_id = s.id';
    $rezultat = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryScalar();
    //$rezultat1 = implode($rezultat);
    //$rezultat2 = implode($rezultat1);
    return $rezultat;
}

}
```

As you can see here there exists relation to "studijskiProgram" here using the "sp_id" foreign key in "predmet". However when I am trying to access "naziv" proprety from "studijskiProgram" in the upper part of the code like this:

```
    array(
        'name'=>'naziv',
        'value'=>$model->studijskiProgram->naziv,
    ),
```

which was the solution with the previous question where CDeatilView widget is used. For some reason the same thing here doesn't work and reports error of trying to get a proprety of a non object. Any idea what to alter so it would work?

Comment: If any column results empty value then also this could be occur. change your line :
 
'value'=>$model->studijskiProgram->naziv
to 
 'value'=>$model->!empty(studijskiProgram->naziv) ?  'value'=>$model->studijskiProgram->naziv : "-",

Comment: what you get if u print $model->studijskiProgram ??

Comment: I don't see the code related to theCDetailView.. please add the related view code if you need a solution for CDetailView ..

Comment: @RK1212 I've fixed it with Ravi's help, it seems that the dataProvider needed to be set up differently, thanks

Comment: @scaisEdge this one was related to a similar widget CGridView not CDetailView therefore for the lack of code related to CDetailView, the issue is solved now, your help with CDeatilView is still greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your code as beow:-

```
 // CGridView column definition:
        'columns'=>array(
            array(
                'name'=>'naziv',
                'value'=>'$data->studijskiProgram->naziv',
                'type'=>'text',
            ),

    // Preparing the DataProvider in the model:
    return new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this),array(
        'sort'=>array(
            'multiSort'=>false,
            'attributes'=>array(
                'naziv'=>array(                
                    'desc'=>'naziv desc',
                ),
```

Comment: Big help man you got it working, thanks so much. If it's not too much trouble would you just clear up what have you done with CActiveDataProvider here, just for the cause of me understanding it properly ?

Comment: This link will explain better than me. :) :- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSort

Answer (score 0):

Yii Gridview takes dataprovider and generate the rows. You can try this one.

Please see here more detail.http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView

```
array(
    'name' => 'naziv',
    'value' => '(isset($data->studijskiProgram->naziv))?$data->studijskiProgram->naziv:""'

),
```

Comment: this actually presented me with some errors as well, for it to work properly the dataProvider in the model needs to be adjusted in the way Ravi has suggested